# gksudo from a non sudoer?

Tags: sudo, security, gui, gksu, gksudo

I want to run gui applications that require admin privileges from gksudo/gksu on a non-sudoer account.  Currently, I can just run `sudo guiapplication` from a sudoer tty, and will be able to display/use the application as a sudoer  most of the time.  There are times when this causes conflicts.  To get around this, I've been trying to use gksu and gksudo.

Both commands

```
    gksudo -slu sudoerusername guiapplication
    gksu -slu sudoerusername guiapplication
```

don't seem to work from the non-sudoer's tty (it says its asking for the sudoer's password, but will only use the non-sudoer's password and says that sudo doesn't allow me to run the command).  I don't really want to use xnest/xhost as it's a pain to limit who can use the xhost.  Anyone know of a way to run gksudo or gksu from a non-sudoer terminal?

EDIT: I've also tried running

```
    export DISPLAY=:0
```

on both the sudoer's and non-sudoer's terminal, and then running gksu/do from the sudoer's terminal, but it says it cannot display on :0.

Comment: Add that user to the sudoers file, or ssh -Y to a user with sudo permission.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try using ssh -Y.

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit your `/etc/sudoers` with visudo add to it:

```
non-sudoer-username localhost=/foo/bar/guiapplication
```

Then gksudo should work for that non-sudoer user and that guiapplication.